# Syntax error: Expected end of input but got identifier "S" in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to have the table where all "entity_type = 'agent'" will appear in final result and only one match with those which "entity_type = 'agency'", because under agencies there are several last_name and first_name so that entity_id will dublicate. But it gives out a result with Expected end of input but got identifier "S" in BigQuery. And I don't know how to fix it. Pls help!

````
N.created_at,
N.entity_id,
N.entity_type,  
N.pageviews_previous_value as pageviews_jul,
N.pageviews_current_value as pageviews_aug, 
N.pageviews_diff_percentage,    
N.likes_previous_value as likes_jul,    
N.likes_current_value as likes_aug, 
N.likes_diff_percentage,    
N.clicks_previous_value as clicks_jul,  
N.clicks_current_value as clicks_aug,   
N.clicks_diff_percentage,   
N.leads_previous_value as leads_jul,    
N.leads_current_value as leads_aug, 
N.leads_diff_percentage,    
N.top_listing_id,   
N.top_listing_pageviews,    
N.top_listing_leads,    
N.top_listing_likes,    
N.average_price_cents_usd_of_productive_listings,
S.first_name,
S.last_name,
S.office_account_type,
S.office_name
FROM `jamesedition-152413.seller_performance.newsletter` N
left join `jamesedition-152413.contacts.all_sellers` S
on N.entity_id = S.agent_id 
where entity_type = 'agent'
UNION distinct
SELECT 
N.created_at,
N.entity_id,
N.entity_type,  
N.pageviews_previous_value as pageviews_jul,
N.pageviews_current_value as pageviews_aug, 
N.pageviews_diff_percentage,    
N.likes_previous_value as likes_jul,    
N.likes_current_value as likes_aug, 
N.likes_diff_percentage,    
N.clicks_previous_value as clicks_jul,  
N.clicks_current_value as clicks_aug,   
N.clicks_diff_percentage,   
N.leads_previous_value as leads_jul,    
N.leads_current_value as leads_aug, 
N.leads_diff_percentage,    
N.top_listing_id,   
N.top_listing_pageviews,    
N.top_listing_leads,    
N.top_listing_likes,    
N.average_price_cents_usd_of_productive_listings,
S.first_name,
S.last_name,
S.office_account_type,
S.office_name
FROM `jamesedition-152413.seller_performance.newsletter` N
left join (
select first_name, last_name, office_id,  
row_number() over (
PARTITION by office_id
order by last_name
) as row_num
from `jamesedition-152413.contacts.all_sellers`
)
`jamesedition-152413.contacts.all_sellers` S
on N.entity_id = S.office_id and row_num = 1
where entity_type = 'office'```
````

Comment: check out the third from bottom line  - it should have `s` ONLY - delete `\`jamesedition-152413.contacts.all_sellers\``  - meantime you still will need to fix your query - for example missing `office_account_type` inside S

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant now it cannot understans what 's' is and gives other problem: Name office_account_type not found inside S

Comment: 1. `s` is alias for subquery. 2. in select statement you reference `s.office_account_type` which does not exists in that subquery

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thanks a lot! I added into _subselect_ _office_account_type_ and _office _name_ and query started working

Comment: great, happy for you! :o)